# Access redux store properties from within the actions in the store itself

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

Currently I have events stored in my events reducer. Now I'm in my actions folder, I am trying to access the value of events which is in my reducer, how would I be able to access such value within the store itself?

[image]

I need to access values stored in the Reducer file in the event.js, through the actions folder in the events.js. How to go about that? Thanks

Comment: Are you using NodeJS as a backend?

Comment: Yes, I've got it hooked up to Graphql but yeah I'm using a node backend. @NeillHerbst

Comment: I think you are trying to do something that actions were not meant to be used for. What is your goal? Why do you need to the values inside your actions?

Comment: @nbokmans After thinking about it and telling myself what I want to do, It has finally clicked and I have another way to solve my issue, thanks!

Comment: With Nodejs you could just export the values and import them in the other file. But I do agree with @nbokmans that maybe you should revise what it is that you want to accomplish

Comment: Yup, this is something that always happens, when you ask yourself sometimes what you want to achieve it simply clicks, thanks for your help anyway guys! Keep it up helping the community! @NeillHerbst